# How to create a HTTP/2 connection using groovy

Tags: groovy, http2

Is there a way that we can create a HTTP/2 connection using groovy. Currently we are creating HTTP/1.1 using openConnection() on the url, but cannot find if we can instruct it that we want to use HTTP/2 connection. Any pointers around it will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) ?

Comment: @cfrick not able to figure out how to define HTTP/2 even with HttpClient.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html see at the bottom

Comment: Will check out the documentation. Thanks a lot @tim